# windows phone 7: loading images from URL crash the application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a pivot, i'm loading images, each image dynamically created as an pivot item and whose source is an URL. It works fine for 10 images, but if there are more images it is crashing.

The problem is no error is shown in the debugging too.
this is the code i'm using to add images as the pivot items

```
foreach (Photo photo in Albumcollection)
            {
                PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();

                Image image = new Image();
                image.Height = 450;
                image.Width = 450;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(photo.URL, UriKind.Absolute);
                image.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
                image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

                image.Margin = new Thickness(0);

                StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
                stackPanel.Children.Add(image);

                pivotItem.Content = stackPanel;
                pivotItem.Header = photo.Name;

                PvtPhotos.Items.Add(pivotItem);

            }
```

What is the reason of crash and what is the solution?

Comment: Does it not throw an exception when it crashes, which would trigger a break into the debugger?

Comment: Is this a limit on the number of items you can have in a pivot? Also why are your using a pivot? Pivots are intended to have a small number of items. Your code could end up with as many as there are images in the collection. You are also likely to have performance issues loading lots of large images at once.

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory?

You can check memory consumption per

[Device Information for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)